# Why a Li-ion battery, when in storage, is better kept around 85% instead of 100%?

Tags: electrochemistry

I discovered that in my laptop settings, I can select an option that is best chosen when the laptop is mainly connected to AC power, and apparently keeps the battery at a lower SOC.
I found this feature also in a Sony smartphone (slightly different operation, it would keep the battery at 90% max during the night, and would fully charge it at dawn) and I found out that's actually good for battery health.

Why is that? What happens inside a battery when it is kept at 100%?

Comment: This topic is discussed multiple times on internet and I guess this site too. In short, at full charge, there are accelerated side reactions decreasing the cell capacity and increasing the cell internal resistance. As the result, the static cell aging is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Could you be more specific?

Comment: It was just a comment, not answer. I was not going to go into details. You can search them out. Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124781/keeping-li-ion-battery-on-charger-vs-plug-the-charger-in-and-out-regularly/124797#124797 and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142688/what-is-the-optimal-voltage-for-storing-a-3-7-v-lithium-polymer-battery/142690#142690

Comment: @Poutnik Let me opine that an advantage of SE sites is peer review *and* clear explanations, something which is frequently lacking from websites and the scientific literature, respectively. So for my money, answers here have a lot more validity than those on arbitrary websites.

Comment: @KennSebesta This approach looks for what is convenient for you, on expense of time and effort of others, adding to it cumulation of redundant info on internet or even the same site. SE sites frown upon questions without signs of prior search effort for exactly these reasons. Asking should be the last, not the first option. Preventing redundant info is part of what makes SE sites great.

Comment: By other words, question policy is part of what helps to separate "seed and weed".

Comment: @Poutnik No disagreement that people should ask last. If this question wasn't valid, though, either because it needs improvement or it's redundant, shouldn't it have been flagged and closed? If I get to this page because I have the same question, it's a bit of a dead-end unless I read the comments. (Great answers in those links, btw!)

Comment: @KennSebesta Question closure is based on a voting system. When I get involved in commenting, I frequently withdraw myself from voting, letting others to decide. In time of search engines, it cannot be a dead end, you could find those links  too, using site:stackexchange.com and few chosen keywords.