# I am using my phone as hotspot. What is the best charging strategy to maximize the lifespan of the battery?

Tags: electrochemistry

*This question could have been asked in Electrical Engineering SE, but I think it is more related with chemistry. It might be a Physics question too. If that is the case I will ask it over there.*

Battery technology of my phone is Li-poly. I have read that Li-poly batteries are quite similar to Li-ion when it comes to maximizing the battery life.

For Li-ion batteries, it is widely recommended to keep the charge levels between 80% and 40%. I have also read that most electric car batteries do not exceed 80%. So, it seems **not** to be a good practice to keep the battery at 100%.

High temperature is also not good for Li-ion batteries. For that reason, fast charging is not recommended as it results in higher temperatures. I only have the stock charger and cannot adjust the charging rate. The application Ampere displays +1470mA (positive) while the phone is charging at 85%, and -300mA (negative) when unplugged at 85%. When the battery was at 99% the charging rate was around +380mA. So it might be that the charger adjusts the charging rate according to the charge level.

At 100%, while the phone is **plugged in**, the voltage is at 4.411V and the charging rate is around +300mA.

At 100%, while the phone is **unplugged**, the voltage is at 4.3V and discharging rate is around -300mA.

So, considering the battery chemistry and the information above, which charging approach is better to maximize the battery lifetime of a phone used as hotspot:

1. Always keep the phone plugged in at 100%?
2. Charge and discharge constantly, i.e charge up to 80%, then leave until 40%, then charge again and so on? 
    *(Note that even shallow cycles cause some damage.)*

What is the best method for the least amount of degeneration in battery?

---

**Edit**
When the phone is left plugged in at 100%, **after some time**, the app Ampere displays **full**. When this happens, the charging rate does not display on the screen and the voltage is stable around 4.35V.

---

**Edit2**
The links @Poutnik provided at the top of his answer do not involve more search effort (in terms of chemistry) than my question. Still they are in much better condition in terms of downvotes.

I specified that I use the phone as a hotspot to give information about the environmental conditions, e.g. how fast the power is being dissipated from the system, which would give an idea about the temperature and the number of chemical reactions happening inside. I also tried to provide the input power to a degree. Because these are what I thought would be needed for a chemist to make a decision. But the phone is a closed system to me and I cannot provide every detail a chemist would need.

If you want to say that *"we are not interested in chemical reactions for specific environmental conditions, especially if it will make some benefit to people"* or *"we don't do science when we are not given every detail"*, then I think you should really question "how and for what reason" we do science.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130442/discussion-on-question-by-xfce4-i-am-using-my-phone-as-hotspot-what-is-the-best).

Comment: I'd prefer not to invoke the "effort" argument, to be honest. That's too easy to misapply, and I don't think it's an issue here at all. The real issue is that the relationship to chemistry is being stretched. There are plenty of things that chemistry can explain. There are plenty of *other* things that may require chemistry as the *foundation* upon which an explanation is constructed; however, not all of those would be valid questions here. Say, for example, explaining the symptoms of a medical disease. This is rooted in chemistry (inter-/intramolecular interactions between biomolecules) [...]

Comment: ... and the *beginning* of an answer may start by talking about proteins, receptors, and ligands, which certainly is chemistry; but it would be a struggle for anybody to reasonably call that kind of question 'chemistry'. Simply adding "I want a chemistry explanation" to the question doesn't help, either, because it doesn't change the underlying question or the correct answer. Of course, it's not black and white: there are degrees of on- or off-topic-ness, and different people may have different opinions. But I strongly suspect the votes indicate that most people think that this is off-topic.

Comment: @orthocresol What field of science would be the most knowledgeable or credible when it comes to battery health in a specific usage pattern? I really thought only a chemist would give a through and reasonable answer to it by explaining the process and therefore clearing all ambiguous points. About medicine, it may well evolve to that in the future.

Comment: I'd suggest electrical engineering or materials science. It's not that chemistry *isn't* related; it's just one step removed, if you get what I mean. Just like how chemistry is one step away from physics or biology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: The short answer would be not to use a device with a battery, as AC powered WifiTo4G hotspot, or a phone without battery or with bypassed battery charging (see below ). Or the phone kept being plugged in all the time.

---

There are closely related CH SE links

- [What is the optimal voltage for storing a 3.7V Lithium polymer battery?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142688/what-is-the-optimal-voltage-for-storing-a-3-7-v-lithium-polymer-battery) and
- [Keeping Li-Ion battery on charger vs plug the charger in and out regularly](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124781/keeping-li-ion-battery-on-charger-vs-plug-the-charger-in-and-out-regularly/124797),

mentioning some chemical aspects of Li-Ion/Pol cell ageing.

But these effects are hard to quantify on basic principles, so evaluating [Scylla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scylla) of high charge and [Charybdis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charybdis) of cell cycling is much easier to be based on empirical principles.

Additionally, there is [A review on Lithium-ion batteries ageing mechanisms and estimations for automotive applications](https://hal-cea.archives-ouvertes.fr/cea-01791260/document), that could be found by easy searching by widely used terms.

As near permanent usage of the phone as the hotspot is required ( mentioned in comments ), the activity would cause high charging/discharging rate with possible hot charging and high dynamic cell wearing. I would prefer static 100% charge here, unless there are electronic means to bypass the cell charging completely.

I recommend consideration the dedicated Wifi2Mobile AC powered hotspot devices for permanent-like usage, or some dedicated older phone.

Alternatively, there is [android.stackexchange.com -
using-android-phone-without-battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174862/using-android-phone-without-battery#:%7E:text=In%20my%20usage%20history%20of,doing%20this%20by%20default...&text=Yes%2C%20some%20phones%20do%20work,and%20it%20works%20just%20fine.,doing%20this%20by%20default...&text=Yes%2C%20some%20phones%20do%20work,and%20it%20works%20just%20fine.) or possibly similar interesting links.

---

Static aging at 100% ( even worse if hot and >85-90%) is reported 5x faster in some older tests than at 40%. This may not be fully true for newer cells due improved cell chemistry/arrangement, or due lovering the nominal "100%" charge level.

Dynamic aging by very shallow cycles is in context of total lifetime charge several times slower than for deep cycles. So lifetime-wise, for small cell loads, ideal would be shallow cycling around 40%. This does not apply for high cell loads if one cannot avoid continuous charging/discharging of partially charged cells.

What the cell would do with low voltage charging source depends on the charging control circuitry of the cell and possibly of the phone too. My guess is the too low voltage source would be rejected by the control circuitry/algorithms.

On my ThinkPad T470 Linux laptop, I have set charging start/stop levels, so both batteries are bypassed halfcharged on AC. I have meant keeping on charger and near end of hotspot session removing the charger so the charge - not the capacity - drops down. In some old tests, 100%/40% charged LiIon drops annually 20%/4% of capacity by static aging.

Comment: The thing is hotspot is almost always active and it is not easy to estimate when it won't be needed. Looks like I will leave it always in charge. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hm, So you use it like a nonstop device. I use frequently my phone as hotspot too, but usually only for working hours period. For like nonstop usage, consider rather some wifi2mobile standalone AC powered hotspot cell providers offer. ( I installed Linux Mint XCFE on 2 obsolete laptops for my friend )